# Why I can only get the default value from the input?

Tags: javascript

I'm super new to JS, and I was writing this little function that supposed to take whatever input from the user and wrap the text at the length of the longest word. All things went well, except I can only get the default value of the input, not the real text someone put there.
My code is:

```js
var inputString = document.getElementById("input").value;
var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
var outputEl = document.getElementById("output");


// find the number of letters in the longest word:
function longest(inputString) {
    let longestWord = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (longestWord < inputArray[i].length) {
            longestWord = inputArray[i].length
        }
    }
    return longestWord
}

var numberOfLetters = longest(inputString);


// wrap the text
function wrap(input, numberOfLetters) {
    let lineLength = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (lineLength + inputArray[i].length <= numberOfLetters) {
            outputEl.innerHTML += inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength += inputArray[i].length + 1 // because there's a space
        } else {
            outputEl.innerHTML += "<br>" + inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength = inputArray[i].length + 1 // space
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<h3>Text Wrapper</h3>
<p id="instructions">We will break your text at the length of your longest word!</p>
<p>Enter Text: <input type="text" id="input" value="put your text here" size='50'></p>
<button onclick="wrap(input.value,numberOfLetters)">Yeah, click me</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

if I type input.value in the console, it returns the value I put into; but if I ask for inputString it returns the default value.
I just don't know what's went wrong here? Can somebody help me?
Sorry if it's a stupid mistake, I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move your var inputString = document.getElementById("input").value; line to the first line of your wrap function.

Comment: You only set `inputArray` value once. Move that splitting code inside the processing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow!

as the comments suggest, you need to set your variable values based on the *current* value of the input.  your current code sets the variables at load-time, and so they get set to the default value and stay that way.  try:

```js
var outputEl = document.getElementById("output");


// find the number of letters in the longest word:
function longest(inputArray) {
    let longestWord = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (longestWord < inputArray[i].length) {
            longestWord = inputArray[i].length
        }
    }
    return longestWord
}



// wrap the text
function wrap(inputString) {
    var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
    var numberOfLetters = longest(inputArray);
    let lineLength = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (lineLength + inputArray[i].length <= numberOfLetters) {
            outputEl.innerHTML += inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength += inputArray[i].length + 1 // because there's a space
        } else {
            outputEl.innerHTML += "<br>" + inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength = inputArray[i].length + 1 // space
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<h3>Text Wrapper</h3>
<p id="instructions">We will break your text at the length of your longest word!</p>
<p>Enter Text: <input type="text" id="input" value="put your text here" size='50'></p>
<button onclick="wrap(document.getElementById('input').value)">Yeah, click me</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

notice that i moved all the variable instantiation to inside the `wrap` function.  i changed the 'longest' function to accept inputArray as its argument, since that's what it's actually using (not inputString) -- this way it doesn't need a global variable.  also i made sure `wrap` call in the button onclick was identifying the input by its id and pass value, then the 'wrap' function needs only this inputString in order to do its process.

Comment: Thank you so much! We never really touched upon the topic of where we should put the variables, and I just asume global variables by default is the better choice. I was wrong!

Comment: usually exactly the opposite ;) . if you can avoid global vars, definitely do so -- closely scoping variables will help you keep your sanity in any language

Answer (score 0):

The script block only executes once and that's why you always get the same value when clicking the button. Moving it to the callback function(which executes every time you click) fixes this problem. Here's the working example of what you need:

```
<body>

<h3>Text Wrapper</h3>
<p id="instructions">We will break your text at the length of your longest word!</p>
<p>Enter Text: <input type="text" id="input" value="put your text here" size='50'></p>
<button onclick="wrap(input.value)">Yeah, click me</button>
<p id="output"></p>

<script>


// find the number of letters in the longest word:
function longest(inputString){
    var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
    let longestWord = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ ) {
        if (longestWord < inputArray[i].length) {
            longestWord = inputArray[i].length
        }    
    }
    return longestWord
}



// wrap the text
function wrap(inputString) {
    var numberOfLetters = longest(inputString);
    var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
    var inputString = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var outputEl = document.getElementById("output");

    let lineLength = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (lineLength + inputArray[i].length <= numberOfLetters){
            outputEl.innerHTML += inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength += inputArray[i].length + 1 // because there's a space
         } else {
            outputEl.innerHTML += "<br>" + inputArray[i] + " ";
            lineLength = inputArray[i].length + 1 // space
        }
    }    

}




</script>
</body>
```